# Feature request: Stack Snippet

Tags: discussion, code

It is possible to get the feature [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/299351) also on WPSE?

At first I think is the default much helpful for snippets with html, css, javascript. Perhaps is enhancement to work with a WordPress back end inside the load of requirements helpful to demonstrate with WordPress core functions.

I think is much helpful to understand the answers, the snippets and easy to see how it works. Currently we use often jsfiddle or similar.

> Why?
>
> Every question is better for having minimal, reproducible code. Right
>   now the best way to tell people to do that is to point them to
>   JSFiddle, which is off-site. Using this feature, we plan to push new
>   posters to embed runnable code that reproduces their problem.
>
> Similarly, answers that include runnable code are easier to use and
>   understand, because you can try them out. Obviously JSFiddle is hugely
>   popular in answers already, so we just wanted to make it even easier
>   to use.
>
> Obviously the same rules apply: code-only questions or answers will
>   still be blocked (and, in fact, because of how it's implemented all
>   the existing checks will just work out of the box).

Answer (score 4):

Recently, our VP of Engineering looked at a [similar request on GIS](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3986/19875):

> I think it wasn't totally obvious from the initial release that snippets are really only for JS/HTML/CSS code (a replacement for jsfiddle.net, basically). A good indicator of whether they'll be useful on a site is the number of answers with javascript in them, and especially posts linking to jsfiddle.

Currently, [126 posts link to jsfiddle.net](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ajsfiddle.net) and of the [58,911 questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions), just [867](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) are tagged [javascript](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript). So from what I see, WordPress doesn't really deal with Javascript enough to be an ideal candidate for this feature. Since [snippets are often misunderstood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused), you might find the feature more annoying then beneficial.

We are looking at [combining the code and snippet shortcuts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets), which might make the feature more palatable on sites that don't embed JavaScript very often. But there's no guarantee it will eliminate confusion.

Comment: It looks like the ratio is about 1 in every 468 questions here on WPSE, but 1 in every 18 questions on SO (543.745/9.799.607). PS: I wonder if there are any search tags like *is:comment*, to count it in comments as well?

Comment: Your values are right. But I think it would be much helpful, that the stack snippet also load a WordPress core, that we can use the core functions to demonstrate a snippet.